# CART Algorithm - why 2^m-1 -1 splits for categorical variables?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, combinatorics, decision-tree

I'm trying to understand more about the CART algorithm and specifically how many splits are considered for categorical variables.

I was reading, both ftp://ftp.boulder.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/support/Stats/Docs/Statistics/Algorithms/14.0/TREE-CART.pdf

and

http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~loh/treeprogs/guide/wires11.pdf

Where they both state that for a categorical variable, CART will consider 2^m-1 -1 splits.

Specifically in the 2nd paper, Professor Loh highlights that with a categorical variable containing 31 discrete values, there will need to be 2^30 -1 splits "on the root node alone".  So nearly 2 billion splits.

I'm really struggling to understand this so clearly I'm misunderstanding part of the process.  If I calculate the number of permutations for a 31 values, it gives me 8.22...e+33 which is clearly way over the 2 billion.  The number of combinations is however 31^2 = 961.

How do we arrive at the need for 2^30 splits in this case?  I can't seem to determine the rule or logic here.  It doesn't seem to be based on combinatorics and I can't see how we need 2 billion splits if we only have 31 values to split on.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

David

Comment: Hint: you want to split the set of levels into two subsets, one for the left subtree and one for the right. How many subsets are there for a set of size m?

Comment: Thank you @HongOoi, stepping away and mowing the lawn while thinking more about it certainly helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2^31 comes from the idea that the algorithm is considering every possible split.  So, there is a set of values for the left child and the rest in the right child.

For instance, if the first two values went to the left, then the splits would be 11000000000000. . . with the "1"s on the left and the "0"s on the right.  Every binary number is a different split (well, actually half are, because the left and right are symmetric).

This is a theoretical idea.  What happens in practice is that the purity measures for each value are determined (31 times).  Then, these are ordered by the estimated target value.  The "higher" values go to the left child and the lower to the right (subject to other conditions, and and allowing for multiple splits and numeric targets).  The algorithm is not doing a brute force comparison of 2^31 different combinations.

The 2^30th comes from simple symmetry.  You can flip the 0s and 1s and get the same split, so 111000000 . . . is the same split as 000111111 . . .  The children are swapped but the purity is the same.  The `- 1` is because a split with all 1s or 0s is not a split at all; the algorithm needs two children for the recursive partitioning part.

Comment: Hello Gordon

Thank you for explaining.  On the basis of your answer, if I had the following numbers of discrete values, I would effectively end up with binary sequences like so...
For 3 values

Val 1 | Val 2 | Val 3
----- | ----- | -----
  0   |   0   |   0   * Not considered
  0   |   0   |   1
  0   |   1   |   1
  0   |   1   |   0
  1   |   1   |   0
  1   |   0   |   1
  1   |   0   |   0
  1   |   1   |   1
Does that largely cover it for the combinations part?

Comment: How frustrating, I can't format in the same way as the main post and it posts the comment whenever I hit enter.

Comment: @Bravid . . . I think you have the point.  For 3 values, there are actually 6 splits -- because 000 and 111 are not of interest:  001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110.  However, by symmetry, 001 and 100 are really the same.  That removes an additional factor of two.  The real point is:  There are a lot of combinations.  Once they are ordered by the target, it is much simpler to find the optimal split.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I see what you mean with 111, but I'm confused about the symetry part for 100 vs 001.  The binary representation for 100 would mean only  Val 1 is present, and 001 would mean only Val 3 is present - I'm just wondering what property or logic we would apply to arrive at an interchangeable equivalent?  Is it effectively based on the position rather than the value so to speak.  So for 4 values we would say 1000 and 0001 are symetrical but no others?

Comment: @Bravid . . . The symmetry is 100-011, 101-010, 110, 011.

Comment: thank you for the responses.  I'm trying to find the specific subject to read more about it and I keep coming up with Binary Symmetric Channel which doesn't at first glance appear to be correct.  Is this just more broadly symmetry in mathematics or is there a specific branch within binary I should be looking for?  Sorry if this is all very basic, it's the first time I've come across this concept.

Comment: @Bravid . . . It is a mathematic observation.

Comment: Hi Gordon, 

Please tell me if I am understanding correct. 
001 means, the 3rd category is in the left, while the first two are on the right side of the split. However, 100, will be that the first category is in the left, while the 2nd and 3rd are in the right. Both of these seem to be different. 
Wouldn't 100 be same as 011, instead? 

Also, in the purity measures, what is meant by purity measure for each value being determined 31 times. It would be great if you can elaborate on this. Maybe with a simple example of 3 categories.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Gordon Thank you for explaining. On the basis of your answer, if I had the following numbers of discrete values, I would effectively end up with binary sequences like so... 
For 3 values

```
Val 1 | Val 2 | Val 3 
----- | ----- | -----
  0   |   0   |   0 * Not considered 
  0   |   0   |   1 
  0   |   1   |   1 
  0   |   1   |   0 
  1   |   1   |   0 
  1   |   0   |   1 
  1   |   0   |   0 
  1   |   1   |   1
```

Does that largely cover it for the combinations part?

I can see the optimisation based on the purity measure could cut out a great deal of repetition but I need to spend some time digesting that part to understand a bit better.

Thank you both for your help.

David